# Vim: cw & dw whitespace inconsistency

Tags: vim, vi

`vim` seems to treat whitespace differently when using `cw` (change word) and `dw` (delete word).

For instance with the example text below, if the cursor is over the letter `a` and I type `dw`, it will remove the remainder of the word *and* the space after, while if I use `cw`, it *dosen't* delete the white space (and leaves you in insert mode as expected).

Example:

```
example text
```

This behavior is confusing as I would have thought the `w` (word) motion would be the same regardless of the `d` (delete) or `c` (change) verb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how it is and this is how it is documented. If you want `cw` to behave like `dw` you can always say

```
:map cw dwi
:map cW dWi
```

See `:help cw` for details. Also look at `w` in `:help cpoptions`.

From the help section for `cw`:

> Special case: When the cursor is in a word, "cw" and "cW" do not include the
> white space after a word, they only change up to the end of the word. This is
> because Vim interprets "cw" as change-word, and a word does not include the
> following white space.
>
> If you prefer "cw" to include the space after a word, use this mapping:
>
> `:map cw dwi`
>
> Or use "caw" (see "aw").

Comment: Thanks, forgot how good the help in `vim` is.

Comment: It's an odd exception. Every other `w` motion goes to the start of the next word, plus it's redundant as `ce` already handles that case.